# Is there a way to multiply all items in a list by an integer?

Tags: python, list

Is there a way to multiply the items from these variables

```
candy_name = ["Assorted Small Lollipops", "Assorted Flavours Small", "Assorted Flavours Large", "Large Lollipop", "100g Assorted Flavours Small", "100g Assorted Flavours Large", "Candy Cane", "100g Candy Canes"]
candy_price = [0.1, 0.05, 0.2, 0.5, 4.5, 6, 0.2, 5.5]
total = 0
candy_order = []
price_order = []
number_order = []
```

```
  if candy in candy_name:
    candy_order.append(candy)
    print()
    print(candy_order,"was added to you order")
    print()
    position = candy_order.index(candy)
    number = input("How many %s would you like? "%(candy))
    try: 
      int(number)
    except ValueError:
      print("Please use integers only.")
      continue
    if int(number) <= 0:
      print("That was not an option, please try again. ")
      continue
    else:
      number_order.append(number)
      candy_total = int(number) * price
      total = total + candy_total
      keep_ordering = input("Would you like to add more to your order? ").lower()
      if keep_ordering == "no":
        break
      elif keep_ordering == "yes":
        continue
      else: 
        print("That was not an option, please use yes or no.")
        break
    break    
  elif candy == " ": 
    break
```

I want to multiply all of the items in "number_order" by price_order.
I have been recommended something like this:

```
for c,p,n in (candy_order, candy_price, number_order):
    print(c, p, n, p * n)
```

Comment: the amount of candy ordered multiplied by what type of candy it is

Comment: Without using an external library (numpy, pandas) you have to process each list item one by one as shown in the last snippet.

Comment: You CAN do that kind of thing with numpy, but in this particular case, what you're doing is probably the best plan.

Comment: every time I try I get an error message, is there a way that you would do it?

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: The error is:"
for c, p, n in (candy_order, price_order, number_order):
    print(c, p, n, p * n)

Answer (score 0):

Your code could probably be optimised slightly like this to see if this solves your problem

```
candy_name = ["Assorted Small Lollipops", "Assorted Flavours Small", "Assorted Flavours Large", "Large Lollipop", "100g Assorted Flavours Small", "100g Assorted Flavours Large", "Candy Cane", "100g Candy Canes"]
candy_price = [0.1, 0.05, 0.2, 0.5, 4.5, 6, 0.2, 5.5]
candy_info = dict(zip(candy_name, candy_price))
candy_order, number_order, total = [], [], 0

while True:
    candy = input("which candy do you want?")

    while candy not in candy_info:
        candy = input("input error, try again:")
    candy_order.append(candy)
    number = input("How many %s would you like? " % candy)

    while not number.isdigit() or int(number) <= 0:
        number = input("Only integers greater than 0 are allowed, try again: ")
    number_order.append(int(number))

    keep_ordering = input("Would you like to add more to your order? y/n")
    while keep_ordering not in ["y", "n"]:
        keep_ordering = input("Simply enter y or n, try again:")

    if keep_ordering != "y":
        for _candy, _number in zip(candy_order, number_order):
            total += candy_info[_candy] * _number
        print("Your total spend is %f" % total)
        break
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to look into my problem and write all that but
I would want to use something that I wrote (mostly). Just because I would like to not get a "not achieved" for my schoolwork. I am allowed to get online help however, I am not allowed to completely copy someone else's work.
Thanks maya.